# Geting error message " E: Unable to locate package qt3-dev-tools"

Tags: installation, wine

I'm trying to install Wine in Ubuntu 13.04 using the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison qt3-dev-tools qt4-qmake
wget -c http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wine/wine-1.6.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf wine-1.6.tar.bz2
cd wine-1.6*
./configure
cd tools
./wineinstall
```

And getting this error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package qt3-dev-tools
```

Tell me what to do. I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: qt3-dev-tools is not there in the 13.04 repo ,hence the error.http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&keywords=qt3-dev-tools . But you can install it using other methods as provided in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can install wine in 13.04 easily by following method:

Open Terminal and execute the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6
$ sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

More [info](http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/) on configuration and use